# Choosing a HTML status code for errors in Express apps

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, error-handling

In my API if any query fails then what should be the response status code?

Example :

```
Grade.find({},function(err,grades) {
    if (err)
      res.status(500).json({error:err,message: 'Somthing went wrong please try again later'});

    else 
     res.status(200).json({grades:grades});         
});
```

Is 500 OK or should it be something else ?

Comment: 500 is ok, but it depends. For example the error can occur because of the provided query then in this case it is 400 bad request error, but if your db shut down accidentally then this error is more likely 500 error. BTW I have created [node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/errorme) for handling errors between your modules and then parsing them into HTTP error code. Check it out it might be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR A 500 status is the closest thing to a 'one size fits all' error, but you can get into much deeper details.**

According to **[the standards](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html)**, you have plenty of choices :

> 5xx Server Error
>
> 500 Internal Server Error
>
> 501 Not Implemented
>
> 502 Bad Gateway
>
> 503 Service Unavailable
>
> 504 Gateway Timeout
>
> 510 Not Extended

You could also create your own 5xx status to differentiate between error types, just try to use numbers that are not defined for anything else.

Or stick to a 500 status and attach the original error code to your result :

`res.status(500).json({error:err, code : err.code, message: 'Somthing went wrong please try again later'})`;

However, before answering with 5xx, you want to make sure that the error doesn't come from the client, by validating the data you receive. If the received data is invalid, use a 400 Bad Request code. If the issue is security related, use a 403 Not Authorized, etc...

Answer (score 0):

According to [http status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) you can use `5xx` for server error and `4xx` for client error.